# Get nearby notification only when application installed

Tags: android, android-intent, beacon, google-nearby

I'm using beacon and nearby service of google.
I registered the beacon using [beacon tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.location.beacon.beacontools&hl=en) of google.
Then I configured it in [google dashboard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/) for an intent in nearby notification:

```
{
  "title": "welcome to my beacon"
  "url": 
  "intent://beacon.myApp.online#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.beacon.myApp; S.uuid=0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b3411;S.major=10;S.minor=8;end"
}
```

Where `beacon.myApp.online#Intent;scheme=http` is my intent I catch in my android app while `package=com.beacon.myApp` is my package and `S.uuid=0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b3411;S.major=10;S.minor=8` are the parameters).

I always get notification from nearby: if the application installed or not in my device.

How can I tell nearby service that won't send me a notification if my application doesn't install in device? Can I do it?

Comment: How can you get the intent if the application is not installed on the device?  How would this be possible?

Comment: You right, it's not possible. I don't want to get the intent if application is not installed, is it possible?

Comment: You will not get it.  The application is not there to receive it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Anyway I get a notification but if the app doesn't install the click on notification takes me to google play (if it install it runs the application and do what it should)